# Why is my table behaving this way?

Tags: html, jstl

I have a table the represents all the product in the cart of customer that has a "remove from cart" button. It enables the user to remove a certain product in the cart. Here is the code:

```
<form
        action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/customer/removeProduct"
        method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="page" value="${page}">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="${productsInCart}" var="product"
                    varStatus="status">
                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="upc"
                            value="${product.getProduct().getUpc()}">
                    <tr class="warning">

                        <td>${product.getProduct().getName()}</td>
                        <td>${product.getQuantity()}</td>
                        <td style="color: green;">&#8369; ${product.totalPrice()}</td>
                        <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"
                            value="Remove from cart"></td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
```

A product is removed by sending its UPC (Universal Product Code) in the controller. However, when the button "remove from cart" button is clicked, the UPCs of all the products in the cart are sent. I don't know why this happens.

Comment: Where is "remove from cart" button the code ? If the button submits the form it will have all the `input: upc` fields from your `${productsInCart}`

Comment: In the last, <td> my friend. <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"
                            value="Remove from cart"></td>

Comment: Got it. It will submit the form with all the UPC so the code is behaving as it should. Seems like you want to try to remove only the product on which remove is called.

Comment: yes, my friend. That's what Im trying to achieve here, remove a specific product in the row where it's clicked.

Comment: Move the form inside the forEach - I posted the answer to show the code with formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the assumption in my comment you can do this:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${productsInCart}" var="product"
            varStatus="status">
            <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/customer/removeProduct" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="page" value="${page}">
                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="upc"
                        value="${product.getProduct().getUpc()}">
                <tr class="warning">

                    <td>${product.getProduct().getName()}</td>
                    <td>${product.getQuantity()}</td>
                    <td style="color: green;">&#8369; ${product.totalPrice()}</td>
                    <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"
                        value="Remove from cart"></td>
                </tr>
            </form>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes. Move the scope of the form inside the for each